# Understanding NGINX HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: git, redirect, nginx, https

I have set up nginx to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name git.mydomain.it;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  

}
```

I can successfully connect via HTTPS and HTTP.

When I do `git clone http://git.mydomain.it/oznt/tracker.git`
I am being prompted with the correct URL:

```
 $ git clone http://git.mydomain.it/oznt/tracker.git
Cloning into 'tracker'...
Username for 'https://git.mydomain.it':
```

So far so good.
But I was wondering what happens when I type my password. Is it being
protected as if I directly connected to `https://git.mydomain.it` or is it first traveling on the wire in clear text to the HTTP end point and then being redirected?

Comment: Found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957699/does-http-redirect-to-https-risk-capture-of-password

Comment: I don't think that this answers your question but you know the question better than me. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be https and you can check it out by looking at the `config` file in the local `.git` folder. Look out for:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://foo.bar.git
```

**EDIT:** As it's written [in the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/contrib/examples/git-clone.sh#L59)

```
http_fetch () {
  # $1 = Remote, $2 = Local
  curl -nsfL $curl_extra_args "$1" >"$2"
```

I expect curl to only follow the redirect ([via -L](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT)), which in essence means, that your password gets indeed transformed in plain via HTTP.

Comment: That does not explain the actual communication taking place between my git client and the git server. How is the password transmitted?

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. Is this a general question about HTTP? Maybe this will help you: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

Comment: I using HTTP to connect. So the connection goes from A->B where A is my computer to B (the server) which then redirects B to C. So the question is what is happening with my password. Is it being sent to from to A to B or from  A to C ?

Comment: I edited my answer and hope that it answers your question. ;)

Comment: I have learned from your answer that link above. In any case, my git is now not listening on plain HTTP anymore.